# Is there any way to force a USB HDD stop spinning after "Safely remove"?

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I have a USB-powered external HDD connected to my DELL laptop. Some times, after clicking on "Safely remove" item in pop-up menu of its icon in side bar, the drive is un-mounted and is removed from `/dev/` folder (`sdb` and `sdb1` both are removed) and `lsusb` do not show the device, but the HDD remains spinning and I could sense the vibration by putting my finger on it. But some times a few seconds after clicking on "Safely remove", it stops spinning and has no vibration. Is there any way (may be a CLI command or a script) to force the drive stop spinning every time after "Safely remove"?
I know that `hdparm` could stop spinning, but works while drive is connected, but I need a way that works after "Safely remove"!

## Note:

When I safely removed the drive I want to keep it plugged-in but not-spinning and not-mounted. Because The access to my laptop USB port is somewhat hard when I fixed my laptop on my desk which is full of extra things and widgets! and also may be I forgot to disconnect the USB port! Considering this, there are two reasons for wanting the drive not-spinning after unmount:

1. If I run laptop on battery, spinning drive uses more energy!
2. If I suddenly take-off my laptop or move it, there may be a damage
   to connected USB-cable or even to the HDD (which is now spinning)!

Comment: Check [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/716782/external-usb-hard-disk-drive-keep-spinning-even-after-safely-remove/717086#717086) to properly remove **external usb hdd**.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, I am guessing what it looks like to me that when you are done with the drive you want to keep it plugged in but not mounted.

So what I would advise you to do is to open the menu and search "Disks" (Ubuntu 14.04/10) if your disk is there, instead of clicking Safely remove I would just click on the pause button on that drive.

Because, it you did not know this, I will tell you that the Safely Removal tool does not do anything beneficial, just as long as your not transferring files it is fine to un-mount it.

Also because the safely removal does is just gets your drive ready for unplugging it. Which in this case you are not, as I take it from what you are asking in this question.

### Hopefully I could be some help!

Comment: Please look at new note added to my question!