# External USB Hard Disk Drive Keep spinning even after safely remove!

Tags: usb

I'm keep digging for a solution for last few days but could not get any solution so far. I use WD Elements 2TB external USB HDD in USB 3.0 port for maximum optimization but the problem is that even after I **safely remove** from my **file manager** or **Unity Dash** it keeps rotating which I can feel very clearly. I'm afraid of unplugging it while spinning and I don't want to take chance.

It can not be my HDD fault as it stops spinning as soon as I safely remove from Windows OS. Also I remember that it was not the same for Ubuntu which I used prior to 14.04 LTS.

Is there any way to fix this in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? I prefer it as simple as **safely remove** option. I don't prefer running any command every-time I've to remove my HDD.

Comment: Could you please run (only once) the command `sudo umount /dev/xxx` (replacing xxx with the name of your HDD, usually 'sdb')? If there are processes using the HDD this command will tell you. Paste the output here.

Comment: @EduardoCola: Command didn't return anything though HDD kept spinning..

Comment: If the command didn't return any output it means you're fine. The spinning animation is probably a bug. You could report it.

Comment: @EduardoCola:  No it can't be a bug!  And it's solved now. Thank you all for you assistance.

Comment: this question must be protected

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using Seagate external HDD drive and I remove my HDD from Ubuntu in two steps:

1. In file manager pressing the small **eject** icon.
2. Then right clicking and **safely remove** the external HDD.

I have not checked for others as I've only Seagate HDD so not sure whether it will work on others but you can give it a try.

Comment: Wow! so finally it worked.. Yes indeed it is working for **WD** as well.. 
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: dude how do you figured out with that!? your answer is insane, thanks a lot, there are a lot of "gold member" users that putted useless commands but your answer truly is the best.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry.  What 'Safe to remove' means that nothing needs to be or is being  written to the drive.  The drive itself needs to slow down from 5200rpm to zero,  This process, obviously,  needs to happen  only after the drive itself finishes ITS read/write cycle.

In other words it is safe to immediately  remove the external drive without creating problems,  but being the self aware paranoid  that I am,  I wait the extra few seconds before removal.  But again,  it is not necessary  to do so.

Comment: But my HDD does not stop spinning even after minutes or hours after Safely Remove!

Comment: I even bricked my HDD doing as you say!